# Using Javascript to autopopulate a PDF field with 110% the value of another field

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm making a PDF form for work, and one of the fields is the total cost. I want another field to autopopulate with the total cost * 1.1.

I have no experience with Java, and haven't been able to hack anything together from other similar threads.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the field that you want the adjusted total add the following line to the custom calculate script. Adjust the field name of the "total cost" field to match the name on your form.

```
event.value = this.getField("total cost").value * 1.1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!